# Preventing Windows Error Dialog for Console App

Tags: c#, dialog, system, activation

I have a .NET service that monitors a windows share location for console apps written in Fortran, launches them, monitors STDOUT and STDERR, and copies output back to a shared location where it's processed by other services. A few instances wrote output that they were terminating, then the app appeared to lock up (it never terminated).  I ran the app that failed with the same input on my local machine, and discovered that there was a memory corruption error caused by, I'm assuming, an attempt to deallocate the same memory twice. A windows error dialog was displayed. I determined that, even though my service was running these console apps as windowless apps, when the error occurred in the Fortran console app it continued "running" because there was no user available to click on the dialog.

Using System.Diagnostics.Process, is there any way to prevent the Windows error dialog? Is there a way to prevent it without making global registry changes? I don't want to turn off this behavior globally.

All I could find by googling this issue, is that the user either 1) Should write appropriate error handling (something that can't be done in Fortran code I don't own), or make changes to the registry (something that I consider wrong because I don't control how other users are using the server).

Comment: Right, using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter() in the Fortran program or disabling Windows Error Reporting are the only decent options you have.  Not much left but a crude Process.Kill() when Process.WaitForExit(int) times out.

Comment: Hans, Thanks for your ideas. These are simulations. Sometimes they run for months. I guess I'm hoping there's a way to turn off that behavior for a specific process.

Comment: Depends on how global "global" is for you: it can be turned off for a single application in Registry: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513617(v=vs.85).aspx